# ¿Cómo puedo instalar windows en un VPS con ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

hay una página que ofrece VPS baratos pero no maneja windows server (evaluación) en sus instalaciones, ¿es posible comprar un VPS con ubuntu e instalar windows server?

edit: no cuenta con virtualización

Answer (score 0):

No entro en temas comerciales, solo técnicos.

#### solución

Si el proveedor te da acceso a las herramientas de máquina del `hipervisor`, y estamos hablando de tecnologías de virtualizacion por `KVM`, `Hyper-V`,... o semejante pero no tecnologia de `contenedores`,si.

Eso quiere decir que en algún lugar (seguramente acceso web) debes enviarle la ISO de Windows, para luego arrancar la máquina e instalarla.